# How to redirect to another url after downloading a file attachment in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

The file which I have generated in django view, after downloading this attachment I need to redirect to other url.

Please someone suggest me how to achieve this or any other method to download file attachment without return response in django view

```
def some view(request):
    with fs.open("filename.pdf") as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=filename.pdf"
        return response

    # Here I want to redirect to other page
```